# SystemC running inside a virtual machine, timing issues or corrupt results?

Tags: virtual-machine, systemc

Is it ok to run a SystemC based simulation on a guest OS inside a virtual machine? Can simulation time be affected by this? I know that SystemC time is simulated and not actually tied to hardware timers.

And will running dozens of instances of SystemC simulations in the virtual machine configured with 4 cores (physical machine has 8) affect the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no problems running SystemC on a virtual machine. I do it regularly with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org). I run SystemC on Linux and Windows virtual machines, both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Unless there is a bug in the virtual machine software, a software application should behave identically when run on a physical or virtual machine.

Running multiple SystemC simulations concurrently on a virtual machine is also fine. The limit to how many simulations you can run concurrently, will be based on how much RAM you have available.